# Push in Datalayer dynamically after Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I need to push the DataLayer after an `ajax` done so that it stays dynamically after a certain user action. The problem is that even bringing everything right out of ajax, in this case the answer to what I need and using the `dataLayer.push` event, this dynamic push does not happen. I have already tried to put the ajax response in elements such as a `button`, `input` and even simulating a click on them, nothing happens. Below is the ajax code.

```
function dadosProdutoCarrinho(id_prod){
     $j.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url : '/datalayer.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
              id_produto: id_prod
          },
          success: function (retorno) {
              console.log(retorno);
              dataLayer.push({
                  retorno
              });
          }
     });
 }
```

In the return(retorno), It returns me the following:

```
  dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'addToCart',
        'ecommerce': {
                'currencyCode': 'EUR',
                'add': {
                        'products': [{
                            'name': 'Product Test',
                            'id': '123',
                            'sku': '123',
                            'price': 27.02,
                            'brand': 'Test',
                            'category': '',
                            'quantity': 1
                        },
                        ]
                }
        }
    });
```

Comment: How does your response (retorno) look like? In the push you need a JSON object that includes a key "event", else the variables will not be updated internally in GTM and you won't be able to use the values.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I updated the question with `ajax` response.